# CSS edit rules page does not open

Tags: 7, theming

I logged in as admin. I opened the css configuration page. I clicked edit rules page. After that, css edit rules page should open but my site is stuck at screen 2(home page). After I click edit rules many times, sometimes, I get the edit rules page. I feel that this is a site wide issue not css injector issue.

Example: If I click Save on views page, it does save but my page gets stuck at the home page. I have to hit the back button to come back to view and I see that views is already saved.

If I click clear cache in performance page, I have similar issue. It does clear the cache but the site is stuck at home page. I hit back button to come back to performance page again.

I simply do not know where to start troubleshooting. I am not getting any error messages. If you could point me to right direction to solve this issue, it would be very helpful.

enter image description here[image]

Screen2:

[image]

Comment: Can you try turning off the overlay?

Comment: ^ seconded. Troublesome.

Comment: Turning off overlay module has fixed the issue. It was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Turned off overlay module. Problem has fixed.